# How do I see a 500 error in dev ops monitoring?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

Learning dev ops...

Looking at logs and metrics and running queries and I can't see what i'm looking for.

I've trigged a `500 error` in my C# api code purposely and I want to see this in the logs/metrics

Tried the Azure Metrics -> Pie Chart of HTTP response codes ->

```
    // Pie chart of HTTP response codes 
// Breakdown of response codes for each metric, over the last 12 hours.  
AzureMetrics 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(12h)  
| where MetricName in ("500", "Http3xx", "Http4xx", "Http5xx") 
| summarize sum(Total) by MetricName  
| render piechart
```

but nothing is showing for 500? any advice I cant seem to find anything on google either...

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried with below query to get the logs related to 500 error in Azure App Service:**

***Query:***

```
requests
| where resultCode =="500"
```

[image]

**Note:**

- Make sure you have configured Application insights in your web app.
- Select scope as Application insights in App service=> Logs.

[image]

[image]

---

**Alternatives to check the error logs:**

1. Create Log Ananlytics workspace in Azure portal.
2. Go to your web app, Add diagnostic settings:

[image]

3. To check the logs, click on the Log Analytics workspace name => Select *Search and analyze* logs (or) Open *logs* in left pane of your web app:
4. As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-troubleshoot-monitor#view-appservicehttplogs-with-log-query), use the below query to get the logs of Http errors:

```
AppServiceHTTPLogs
| where ScStatus == 500
```

Other way to check the error logs in web app:

- Enable application logging in App Service=> Monitoring=>App Service Logs.

[image]

- You can track the logs in **Logs stream**:

[image]

**References:**

[Tutorial: Troubleshoot with Azure Monitor - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-troubleshoot-monitor#view-appservicehttplogs-with-log-query)